# how to create a special pattern for password with crunch

Tags: kali-linux

im trying to create specific pattern for creating password via crunch but didnt found anywhere somthing like that and wanna now if it even possibale.
for example i want to make as pattern thw word "password" but i want that the letter p could be lowcase or highcase, and the letter a could be a or @ and the s could be s/$.
so i try somthing like
`crunch 10 10 pP+a@+s$word -t`
but it not seems right.
try to lock allready in bunch of guide but didnt found way to make spesific char to been choseen from a spesicifc option.
any suggestion?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
crunch 8 8 pP a@ s$ s$ -t @,^^word
```

Gives the output:

```
password
pas$word
pa$sword
pa$$word
p@ssword
p@s$word
p@$sword
p@$$word
Password
Pas$word
Pa$sword
Pa$$word
P@ssword
P@s$word
P@$sword
P@$$word
```

If you want to write to a file, append this at the end: `-o file.txt`